# How to make the for each loop function in C++ work with a custom class

Tags: c++, list, c++11, foreach

I'm new to C/C++ programming, but I've been programming in C# for 1.5 years now. I like C# and I like the List class, so I thought about making a List class in C++ as an exercise.

```
List<int> ls;
int whatever = 123;
ls.Add(1);
ls.Add(235445);
ls.Add(whatever);
```

The implementation is similar to any Array List class out there. I have a `T* vector` member where I store the items, and when this storage is about to be completely filled, I resize it.

Please notice that this is not to be used in production, this is only an exercise. I'm well aware of `vector<T>` and friends.

Now I want to loop through the items of my list. I don't like to use `for(int i=0;i<n; i==)`. I typed `for` in the visual studio, awaited for Intellisense, and it suggested me this:

```
for each (object var in collection_to_loop)
{

}
```

This obviously won't work with my List implementation. I figured I could do some macro magic, but this feels like a huge hack. Actually, what bothers me the most is passing the type like that:

```
#define foreach(type, var, list)\
int _i_ = 0;\
##type var;\
for (_i_ = 0, var=list[_i_]; _i_<list.Length();_i_++,var=list[_i_]) 

foreach(int,i,ls){
    doWork(i);
}
```

My question is: is there a way to make this custom List class work with a `foreach-like` loop?

Comment: you can write a `begin()` and a `end()` member functions and an iterator type for your class to make it foreach compatible.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Firstly, the syntax of a `for-each` loop in `C++` is different from `C#` (it's also called a `range based for loop`. It has the form:

```
for(<type> <name> : <collection>) { ... }
```

So for example, with an `std::vector<int> vec`, it would be something like:

```
for(int i : vec) { ... }
```

Under the covers, this effectively uses the `begin()` and `end()` member functions, which return iterators. Hence, to allow your custom class to utilize a `for-each` loop, you need to provide a `begin()` and an `end()` function. These are generally overloaded, returning either an `iterator` or a `const_iterator`. Implementing iterators can be tricky, although with a vector-like class it's not too hard.

```
template <typename T>
struct List
{
    T* store;
    std::size_t size;
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;

    ....

    iterator begin() { return &store[0]; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return &store[0]; }
    iterator end() { return &store[size]; }
    const_iterator end() const { return &store[size]; }

    ...
 };
```

With these implemented, you can utilize a range based loop as above.

Comment: @RicardoPieper Note that range based for loops are only available in the latest version of visual studio (2012).

Comment: So it won't compile in any other compiler/IDE?

Comment: @RicardoPieper It'll compile in any version of Clang or gcc from the past few years (4.7 upwards for gcc I think, not sure about Clang version).

Comment: OK, that's enough for me, since I use VS2012 for my programming things. I had success implementing the iterators, easy as pie.

Comment: I don't think the answer is complete. You implicitly assume that List::iterator has some functionality (which in this case you got for "free" because iterator is a pointer. This isn't the general case). What are the assumption on the iterator type? Is it operator++ and  operator==.  anything else?

Comment: It's been 4 years, but I was wondering the same. I think @masterxilo's answer clarifies it a lot. For the sake of simplity, however, I'm keeping this one as the accepted answer.

Comment: How to jump over elements? For example if i have a map i want to show only elements != nullptr

Answer (score 51):

Let `iterable` be of type `Iterable`.
Then, in order to make

```
for (Type x : iterable)
```

compile, there must be types called `Type` and `IType` and there must be functions

```
IType Iterable::begin()
IType Iterable::end()
```

`IType` must provide the functions

```
Type operator*()
void operator++()
bool operator!=(IType)
```

---

The whole construction is really sophisticated syntactic sugar for something like

```
for (IType it = iterable.begin(); it != iterable.end(); ++it) {
    Type x = *it;
    ...
}
```

where instead of `Type`, any compatible type (such as `const Type` or `Type&`) can be used, which will have the expected implications (constness, reference-instead-of-copy etc.).

Since the whole expansion happens syntactically, you can also change the declaration of the operators a bit, e.g. having *it return a reference or having != take a `const IType& rhs` as needed.

Note that you cannot use the `for (Type& x : iterable)` form if `*it` does not return a reference (but if it returns a reference, you can also use the copy version).

Note also that `operator++()` defines the *prefix* version of the `++` operator -- however it will also be used as the postfix operator unless you explicitly define a postfix `++`. The ranged-for will not compile if you only supply a postfix `++`, which btw.can be declared as `operator++(int)` (dummy int argument).

---

Minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int Type;

struct IType {
    Type* p;
    IType(Type* p) : p(p) {}
    bool operator!=(IType rhs) {return p != rhs.p;}
    Type& operator*() {return *p;}
    void operator++() {++p;}
};

const int SIZE = 10;
struct Iterable {
    Type data[SIZE];

    IType begin() {return IType(data); }
    IType end() {return IType(data + SIZE);}
};

Iterable iterable;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for (Type& x : iterable) {
        x = i++;
    }
    for (Type x : iterable) {
        printf("%d", x);
    }
}
```

output

```
0123456789
```

---

You can fake the ranged-for-each (e.g. for older C++ compilers) with the following macro:

```
 #define ln(l, x) x##l // creates unique labels
 #define l(x,y)  ln(x,y)
 #define for_each(T,x,iterable) for (bool _run = true;_run;_run = false) for (auto it = iterable.begin(); it != iterable.end(); ++it)\
     if (1) {\
         _run = true; goto l(__LINE__,body); l(__LINE__,cont): _run = true; continue; l(__LINE__,finish): break;\
         } else\
            while (1)   \
                if (1) {\
                    if (!_run) goto l(__LINE__,cont);/* we reach here if the block terminated normally/via continue */   \
                    goto l(__LINE__,finish);/* we reach here if the block terminated by break */\
                }   \
                else\
                l(__LINE__,body): for (T x = *it;_run;_run=false) /* block following the expanded macro */                         

 int main() {
     int i = 0;
     for_each(Type&, x, iterable) {
         i++;
         if (i > 5) break;
         x = i;
     }
     for_each(Type, x, iterable) {
         printf("%d", x);
     }
     while (1);
 }
```

(use declspec or pass IType if your compiler doesn't even have auto).

Output:

```
 1234500000
```

As you can see, `continue` and `break` will work with this thanks to its complicated construction. 
See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/mp/ for more C-preprocessor hacking to create custom control structures.

Answer (score 9):

That syntax Intellisense suggested is not C++; or it's some MSVC extension.

C++11 has [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for iterating over the elements of a container. You need to implement `begin()` and `end()` member functions for your class that will return iterators to the first element, and one past the last element respectively. That, of course, means you need to implement suitable [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) for your class as well. If you really want to go this route, you may want to look at [Boost.IteratorFacade](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html); it reduces a lot of the pain of implementing iterators yourself.

After that you'll be able to write this:

```
for( auto const& l : ls ) {
  // do something with l
}
```

---

Also, since you're new to C++, I want to make sure that you know the standard library has several [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) classes.

Comment: Hi, your answer was very good too, but sadly I can't accept 2 answers. And thanks for the links :D

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not have the `for_each` loop feature in its syntax. You have to use c++11 or use the template function [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Sum {
    Sum() { sum = 0; }
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }

    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 9, 15, 267};

    std::cout << "before: ";
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int &n){ n++; });
    Sum s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Sum());

    std::cout << "after:  ";
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "sum: " << s.sum << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @yngum suggests, you can get the VC++ `for each` extension to work with any arbitrary collection type by defining `begin()` and `end()` methods on the collection to return a custom iterator.  Your iterator in turn has to implement the necessary interface (dereference operator, increment operator, etc).  I've done this to wrap all of the MFC collection classes for legacy code.  It's a bit of work, but can be done.