# [Newbie]Store the element of an list in a variable (in loop)

Tags: c++, list

`for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        float temp;
        temp = List1.(i)
        if(temp<0){
       //do smth
}
}`

So I want to store every next element(i) of the list in a variable and then check if that element is smaller than 0 (<0).I am getting stuck with what should I write after `temp=List1.`.I am sorry for my beginner question!!!I am using C++.

Comment: What is the type of `List1`?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I don't do C++

You should tell us what language you are using, and before asking a question that you yourself point as a newbie qustion you shoud search first, young padawan.

If it's java then check this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

But in many languages this should do :

```
if(temp<0){
  //do something
}
```

For C++ : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Iteration in C++ : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

or if you want to use the foreach : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Here is an answer found on SO that should help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16504109/4088809

looks like what you nee is

```
for(<type> <name> : <collection>) { ... }
```

if your list is contains int then

```
for(int i : vec) {
  if(i<0){
    // do your thing
  }
}
```

Comment: then does my answer suit you or is it something else?

Comment: I know what should I type after IF operator , my questions is to ( List1. .....) What should I use to get the every next element using the ''i'' from the loop.

Comment: so your question is about iteration: how to iterate over each element of the list and if it is <0 then you do something with it. right ?

Comment: yep , something like "temp=List1.ref(i)" but I dont know the operator after ''List1''