# implement iterator over file

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to create a class with a loaded file and implement an iterator for given class to iterate over it with range iterator

Here is my class

```cpp
class Csv
{

  public:
    explicit Csv(std::string filepath);
    ~Csv();
    void load_new_file(std::string filepath) {}

  private:
    std::ifstream file;
};
```

Here is a behaviour I want to implement

```cpp
Csv csv("path");
for (auto line : csv ){
    std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your `begin()` could return a [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). You'll have to figure `end()` out - but it's similar :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the for each loop function in C++ work with a custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504062/how-to-make-the-for-each-loop-function-in-c-work-with-a-custom-class)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, sounds like cheating. :)

Comment: Additional information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: @SimonKraemer thank you for your input, but no. My problem is I don't know how to implement `begin()` and `end()` for ifstream, I will look into `std::istream_iterator`

Comment: @Hubert, is it some kind of assignment or you need it for some real project?

Comment: @Evg real project

Comment: And what is semantics of iteration? Line by line or comma-separated-values as class name suggests?

Comment: @Evg line by line, I will handle commas and other csv separators using boost::tokenizer when needed on each line

Comment: @Hubert Here is an overview of the different kind of iterators and the requirements/specifics they are supposed to fulfil/have: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator

Comment: And if you don't need some special thing in the boost tokenizer, you also have the [`std::regex_token_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) that is included in standard c++.

Comment: And "abc def" without a line break should produce one line or two lines?

Comment: @Evg one line, the iteration over `Csv class` should behave like `getline(std::ifstream, std::string)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Too bad `istream_iterator` is not bidirectional - would be a rather elegant solution.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes, that's true. I can't imagine it being very hard to write one especially made for `fstream`s if that's needed though.Your link to the list of iterator categories may help OP to select which category the iterator should be in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal example that uses `std::getline`:

```
class End_iterator {};

class Iterator {
public:
    Iterator(std::ifstream& file) : file_{file} {
        next();
    }

    const std::string& operator*() const {
        return str_;
    }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        next();
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(End_iterator) const {
        return !!file_;
    }

private:
    void next() {
        std::getline(file_, str_);
    }

    std::ifstream& file_;
    std::string str_;
};

class Csv {
public:
    explicit Csv(std::string filepath) {
        file_.open(filepath);
    }

    auto begin() {
        return Iterator{file_};
    }

    auto end() {
        return End_iterator{};
    }

private:
    std::ifstream file_;
};
```

C++17 allows us to use `begin` and `end` iterators of distinct types in a range-based for loop. It is easier (and somewhat more elegant) to make `End_iterator` a distinct type (a sentinel).

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example of a custom iterator that satisfies the [*LegacyInputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) requirements:

```
class LineFileIterator
{
public:
    using value_type = std::string;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = const std::string&;
    using pointer = const std::string*;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    LineFileIterator(): file(nullptr) {}
    explicit LineFileIterator(std::ifstream& f): file(&f) {}
    
    LineFileIterator& operator++()
    {
        read();
        return *this;
    }
    LineFileIterator operator++(int)
    {
        LineFileIterator tmp = *this;
        read();
        return tmp;
    }
    
    const std::string& operator*() const
    {
        return currentLine;
    }
    
    friend bool operator!=(const LineFileIterator& a, const LineFileIterator& b)
    {
        return not a.equal(b);
    }
    
    friend bool operator==(const LineFileIterator& a, const LineFileIterator& b)
    {
        return a.equal(b);
    }
private:
    bool equal(const LineFileIterator& it) const
    {
        return file == it.file;
    }
    
    void read()
    {
        if(not std::getline(*file, currentLine))
        {
            file = nullptr;
        }
    }

    std::ifstream* file;
    std::string currentLine;
};
```

The begin method should return LineFileIterator{file}, and end method should return a default constructed LineFileIterator.

Edit: This implementation works since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ 17 the range based for has been implemented like this

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ;
  auto __begin = begin_expr;
  auto __end = end_expr;
  for (;__begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
  }
}
```

You may check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

If you want to make you class suitable for using the range based for loop, you should define 5 functions:

- begin()
- end()
- operator *()
- void operator ++()
- bool operator != (...& other)

And because you want that your class **has** an iterator and NOT **is** an iterator, we will simply define an internal iterator to the underlying data structure and do all operations with this iterator.

That's a difference to the other answers, where the whole class **is** an iterator.

This makes life real easy.

Reading the complete file is a one-liner.

By the way, parsing the file is also a one liner by using `std::regex_token_iterator`. There is no need for boost or something. Reading a file and splitting it into Tokens is als a typical one-liner.

Please see the simple program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using Lines = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex re{ "," };

class Csv {
    // Here we staore all lines of the file
    Lines lines{};

    // Local iterator to this lines
    Lines::iterator lineIterator{};

    // Function to read all lines of the file
    void readData(const std::string& fileName);

public:
    // Simple constructor
    explicit Csv(std::string fileName) { readData(fileName); }
    ~Csv() {};

    // Iterators to access the lines data
    Lines::iterator begin() { lineIterator = lines.begin(); return lineIterator;  };
    Lines::iterator end() { lineIterator = lines.end(); return lineIterator; };
    std::string& operator *() { return *lineIterator; }
    void operator ++() { ++lineIterator; }
    bool operator != (const Lines::iterator& other) { return other != lineIterator;  }
};

void Csv::readData(const std::string& fileName) {

    // Open File and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream fileStream{ fileName }; fileStream) {

        // Clear old existing data
        lines.clear(); 

        // Read all lines
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(fileStream, line); lines.push_back(line))
            ;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
}

int main() {

    // Open file and read all lines
    Csv csv("r:\\text.txt");

    // Range based for for iterating over the lines in the file
    for (const std::string& line : csv) {
        std::cout << "\n\n" << line << "   ->\n";

        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), {}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\t"));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what `lineIterator = lines.begin();` in `begin()` and `end()` is for. Also note that your member functions `operator*()`, `operator++()`, and `operator!=()` are not called at all.